# Tradução do verbo aproveitar para Inglês

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução, português-europeu

Neste tipo de frase:

> Já que vais sair aproveita e leva o lixo.

Qual é a maneira mais correta de se traduzir o verbo `aproveitar` com o sentido de tirar vantagem do tempo/ação planeada para também fazer outra coisa?

Do tipo, já que vais fazer uma coisa que ajuda em outra coisa que também precisa ser feita, faz também essa segunda coisa.

As opções que eu consigo pensar não me parecem traduzir exatamente o sentido mas penso que são as únicas maneiras.

> Since you're going out _____ and take the trash.

1. `go ahead` (`procede`)
2. `take advantage` (`tira vantagem`)

A primeira parece que se está a dar permissão em vez de estar a pedir um favor.

A segunda parece que está a dar o conselho de tirar vantagem de uma situação.

Talvez se utilizar `would you please go ahead`, apesar de nem sempre ser usado como um favor mas também como uma ordem.

Com o verbo no início da frase ainda parece mais complicado traduzir:

> Aproveita já que vais sair e leva o lixo.

Comment: Esse "aproveita" corresponde mais ou menos a "take the opportunity", mas isso é uma maneira de a gente falar em português. Em inglês, o que me parece mais natural é "since you're going out will you take out the rubbish?"ou "...would you/could you" ou "do you mind taking". O papel do "aproveita" fica subentendido. E pelo menos em Inglaterra seria natural acrescentar um "please". Mas eu não sou falante nativo. Para estas coisas poderias perguntar no ELU ou ELL; eles saberão melhor. Naturalmente, terias de explicar o significado e função do "aproveita" na frase em questão.

Comment: Também poderia dizer qualquer coisa como "since you're going out, you could take out the rubbish while you are at it". Este "while you are at it" é usado mais ou menos para o mesmo fim que o nosso "aproveita". Talvez seja excessivo neste caso concreto. Novamente, falantes nativos podem aconselhar melhor.

Comment: @Jacinto Muito boas sugestões. E eu a pensar que não havia muitas alternativas sem ser as que eu tinha dado mas estava enganado. Obrigado.

Comment: user73... (não queres arranjar um nome mais personlizadol?) na verdade eu nem creio que as tuas alternativas sejam válidas. Nunca ouvi "take advantage" ou "go ahead" (ou "take the opportunity") neste contexto. Se ouvisse, pensaria que era gracejo. Tipo, "since your're going out, go ahead and take out the rubbish" soa-me como "já que vais sair, se tás com muita vontade de levar lixo, pá, força, não faças cerimónia".

Comment: There are many, many ways to translate this. Adding please though is not one of them. You have to decide: Do you want an accurate translation of aproveitar or are you looking to make some dialogue or other be culturally relevant? The two things can be very different. I am a native English speaker and I could list at least 15 different ways of asking someone to "also take out the trash (AmE) or rubbish (BrE). So, what are you looking for? A translation or an adaptation/localization? Or, third option, one that does both? That's what I tried to give you in my answer.

Comment: The problem with dictionaries is that they do not always provide solutions at the contextual level of a "material realization" (i.e. how people actually speak) of the language.

Comment: I think I'm looking more for a translation than an adaptation/localization. Though, having both would be of greater value. You can still edit your answer if you want to [include more information in it](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/5990#comment15448_5995).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aos meus ouvidos, a melhor tradução nesse contexto informal não inclui o "aproveita". Eu sugeriria simplesmente:

> Since you're going out, (please) take the trash (out) too.

Contudo, como de costume, a melhor tradução depende do contexto: num em que mais do que um relativamente neutro "aproveite (a oportunidade)", tem-se uma exortação, então o "go ahead" é uma boa opção, já que pode ser usado para encorajamento.

"Take advantage" significa realmente "tirar vantagem. Mas uma construção como "take the chance" é possível, embora possa conferir um caráter especial ao "sair" que ele usualmente não tem. Também rebuscadas seriam opções similares como "take/use the occasion/opportunity".

Comment: "Take the opportunity" soa-me muitíssimo--íssimo, íssimo--mais natural que "use the chance". Isto em geral, porque neste caso concreto eu também não incluiria o "aproveita", como disse nos comentários acima. (Curioso, eu escrevi aqui este comentário antes, até mais longo, porque foi antes dos comentários à pergunta, mas devo ter feito alguma borrada.)

Comment: @Jacinto Fui verificar e, de fato, o "use the chance" é muitíssimo menos usado que o "take the chance" ou, empatado, "take the opportunity" ([Ngram viewer do Google](https://bit.ly/2QjADcq)). Obrigado. Agora, qual desses dois últimos soa mais rebuscado, imagino que nem falantes nativos concordem entre si - por via das dúvidas, editei a resposta e coloquei todos no mesmo nível.

Comment: a resposta está bem coerente. Pela experiência que tenho convivendo com americanos e comparando com brasileiros, os americanos são mais diretos ao falar, "sem rodeios", como o brasileiro, por exemplo.

Comment: This does not translate the word at all. And there is no please at all.

Comment: Stafusa, olha que "take the chance" nalguns contextos significa 'arriscar'. Em "take the chance to", "chance" normalmente significa 'oportunidade', mas "take the chance to" está a 6% de "take the opportunity to" no Google Books. É claro que isto é uma questão lateral: eu não usaria nada disto para a frase em questão. A acrescentar alguma coisa à frase básica ("since you're going out, take ou the rubbish") para corresponder diretamente ao nosso "aproveita", a única coisa que me ocorre é o "while you are at it".

Comment: @Jacinto Por que você não reúne tuas sugestões e comentários nessa questão numa resposta? Acho muito válidos e, além disso, embora nosso maior desafio para sair do beta seja a frequência de perguntas (teria que ser multiplicada por 20 vezes!), o número de repostas por pergunta também está baixo. :-)

Comment: @Jacinto Sobre o "take the chance", não seria mais comumente "take **a** chance" para significar "arriscar" ou "tentar a sorte"?

Comment: Eu sinto uma certa relutância em responder a perguntas deste tipo, a maneira ideal de exprimir uma ideia em inglês: o forum ideal é o ELU. "Take a chance" é normalmente 'arriscar'; mas eu dei uma vista de olhos, e "take the chance" também aparece com o significado 'arriscar', especialmente quando na negativa: I don't want to take the chance of (qualquer coisa indesejável).

Comment: Olha, nem mais, estou a ver "Witness for the prosecution" (1957). Um tipo quer ir com uma cantora para a casa dela; incentiva-a com uma oferta de café (pouco depois da guerra, devia ser coisa preciosa)  e pergunta-lhe se ela tem água em casa. Ela responde "sometimes", e ele, "let's take the chance".

Comment: Eu concordo com [stafusa](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/5990#comment15441_5995) que seria uma boa contribuição ter uma resposta tua @Jacinto. Há boas sugestões nos comentários que não estão em nenhuma das respostas atuais. Penso que o melhor seria ter as várias maneiras diferentes de o dizer pela ordem de utilização e/ou com uma explicação de uso e sentido das opções. Algo como: `Since you're going out ____ take out the rubbish (while you are at it)?` 1 `will/would/could you`; 2 `do you mind taking`; 3 `take/use the occasion/opportunity/chance to`; 4 `you could`; 5 `go ahead and`.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Já que vais sair aproveita e leva o lixo.

Since you're going out, go ahead and take the trash (out), too.

*go ahead na linguagem falada não quer dizer "dar permissão".*

Go ahead and do something **é só para dar ênfase no que se fala.**

**Existe o uso informal de go ahead em resposta à uma pergunta e existe o uso formal como verbo**.

We cannot go ahead [proceed] with the work today.

Comment: Eu diria que, mais do que apenas dar ênfase, o "go ahead and do something" significa "tomar a iniciativa e fazer algo".

Comment: @stafusa Yes, but not here. Since you're doing x, go ahead and do y. That is not initiative, that is aproveitar.

Comment: I'm no native speaker, but I find it strange that I never met this usage before, and I can't find it mentioned in the few dictionaries I checked either. You're sure you remember correctly?

Comment: Nem tudo na linguagem falada e ao nível do discurso se encontra em dicionários. Se fosse o caso, a funcão do/de tradutor não teria nenhum sentido....And I am a native speaker. Claro, nem sempre é necessário traduzir cada palavrinha. Ao inverso, as vezes uma palavrinha pode marcar uma ponto importantíssimo na fala de uma pessoa. Por exemplo, num caso criminoso ou num contexto hospitalar. Claro, para um diálogo em Netflix talvez nem seria traduzido. E sempre o contexto que "manda" no tradutor.....

Comment: Eu sei, Lambie, acho inclusive que mesmo se todos os significados estivessem dicionarizados, isso pouco contribuiria para tirar o emprego dos tradutores. Agora, certamente dou um peso maior à opinião de nativos, mas mesmo pessoas que compartilham um dialeto (no sentido linguístico) podem discordar sobre significados - basta ver as opiniões discordantes sobre português aqui no Portuguese SE - é normal isso, pois cada um constrói seu vocabulário a partir de suas experiências individuais. Só pedi confirmação porque desconhecia e estranhei mesmo, e penso que as pessoas podem se equivocar.

Comment: @stafusa Tudo bem, tradução é f*** mesmo. :)

Answer (score 2):

Considerando que a frase original não tem "por favor", nem "também", eu traduziria simplesmente para:

Since you're going out, **also** take the trash.